# Is it possible to configure more than 1 email account to ThunderBird

Tags: email, thunderbird

Is it possible to **configure more than 1 email account to thunderbird**.
for eg: my gmail and yahoo account.can i configure both to thunderbird.
Different chats like google talk,facebook chat can be configured in thunderbird.so same thing is possible for mails also??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to add more than one account to thunderbird.

This is possible via Account-Settings (in the menu edit on linux).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see [this explanation from Mozilla](https://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/manual-account-configuration).

Short version:

- Open the Account Settings (**Tools | Account Settings**). Each email or newsgroup account that has already been configured is listed on the left side of the Account Settings dialog.
- Click the **Account Actions** button and select **Add Mail Account**.
- Enter your email account details and press **Continue**.

Comment: thnks for replying